# Batch Script ErrorLevel Output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need help - I am trying to output any ErrorLevel that is 1 or greater into a log file. When I issue the command the log file never get's generated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Script:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\_\Restart\Computer.txt) do (
start "%%i" \_\PStools\psexec \\%%i -u Administrator -p Password -i c:\restart.cmd
if not %errorlevel%==0 echo %errorlevel% > error.log
)
```

This script allows me to use PSEXEC and issue a restart command to all the computer at once. However several of them fail and I'd like to know which ones fail.

Thanks!

Is this the format I should use?

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\_\Restart\Computer.txt) do (
start "%%i" \_\PStools\psexec \\%%i -u Administrator -p Password -i c:\restart.cmd
if errorlevel 1 echo !errorlevel! > error.log
)
```

Comment: You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for `!errorlevel!`...

Comment: What will that look like in the code? I'm trying it several ways and nothing is working so far.

Comment: Place `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` on top of your script and exchange `%errorlevel%` by `!errorlevel!`. Alternatively, simply replace `if not %errorlevel%==0` by `if errorlevel 1` (meaning equal to or greater than `1`)...

Comment: The script will not execute - please see revised code above.

Comment: You probably also need to use `>>` instead of `>`. You're overwriting the file.

Comment: @shawnt00 - I replaced with your suggestion. The script doesn't execute the command to restart and the error.log file still doesn't update with the error value/code.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing a little testing. I think you still want to append but it doesn't address your problem.

Comment: I think you hadn't previously mentioned that the restart command never runs. What are you actually seeing?

Comment: @shawnt00 What I am seeing: When i run the above script the command prompt opens then closes very quickly (no errors that i can see) and the error.log file is not updated. I wonder if i don't have the code in the correct order -  but i have switched it around anyway i can think of and still will not work. If i remove the error level coding and go back to original script it works perfectly - but doesn't log any errors.

Comment: Why are you using `start`? Can you launch the script without it? I don't think you're going to get useful errorlevels from `start` anyway.

Comment: Only using "start" because that's the only way i know how to execute the script. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Try just running `psexec` with all its arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script V3:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\temp\list.txt) do (
start "" "shutdown" /m \\%%i -r -f -t 900
echo !errorlevel! && echo %%i
if errorlevel 1 echo !errorlevel! >> c:\temp\log.txt && echo %%i >> c:\temp\log.txt
)
```

-m = use remote computer

-r = reboot

-f = Force reboot

-t = delay of time before rebooting

you can use shutdown -? for more help on argument that can be passed to the reboot command.

Script v4 without the start command:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\temp\list.txt) do (
shutdown /m \\%%i -r -f -t 900
echo !errorlevel! && echo %%i
if errorlevel 1 echo !errorlevel! >> c:\temp\log.txt && echo %%i >> c:\temp\log.txt
)
```

Comment: This does not work. When i execute the script the cmd opens then closes very quickly with no errors. All this script is trying to do is look into a text file with hostnames and use PSEXEC to execute the restart.cmd script remotely all at the same time. I am trying to capture the error code for when the command didn't execute (for whatever reason). Do you think there's a better way of doing the script?

Comment: I guess you have admin right on the remote computer so you could use the built in windows command "shutdown" instead of calling psexec maybe this would help.`code for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\Restart\Computer.txt) do ( shutdown /m \\%%i >> c:\temp\log.txt) `

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the new code without using psexec.

Comment: The script executed. However the script would only restart 1 computer out of the list of 100 that I have. For the script I have to be able to restart all computers at the same time. Is that possible? Also the ErrorLevel, even though computer successfully restarted it still shows Error 53, same error that is used when i put a bogus hostname in.

Comment: I tested with a liste of 4 computer, one per line and it returned me 0 for the computer with success and 53 for computer it could not reach. Also I just checked with another workstation that has windows firewall enable and the operation was not successfull so windows firewall might be an issue. The script as is will display on screen those with success and in the log file those with error.

Comment: The script worked! However, it has tpop o restart the computers 1 by 1 - Is there a way to make them restart all at the same time? In the previous script I had it would pop up several boxes and reboot the computers all at the same time.

Comment: change the shutdown line with this:
`code start "" "shutdown" /m \\%%i -r -f -t 900 `
Script updated to v3 in original answer. Don't forget to mark as answer if the script fulfill your need.

Comment: The script worked Great! the only thing is that the when the script executes - even if you have a bogus hostname or the shutdown command does not execute correctly it will still show up as error code 0 (successful) so nothing goes into the log file saying what computers aren't rebooting. Do you know why that is?

Comment: i remember seeing somewhere that the start command doesn't handle return code well. Your best bet would probably to use the script without the start command which was then outputting correctly to the log file but then that implies that there is a few second delay on the reboot command for the next host if the current one doesn't respond since it has to wait for the timeout before proceeding with the next one. I'll add script V4 to my answer.

Comment: The problem is with the "start" command, the return will always be "success" as action was run "shutdown". To go around that we need start /WAIT but then we're back to shutting computer one after the other and not all at the same time. Your best bet would probably to use the script without the start command which was then outputting correctly to the log file but then that implies that there is a few second delay on the reboot command for the next host if the current one doesn't respond since it has to wait for the timeout before proceeding with the next one. I'll add script V4 to my answer.